# Is there any complete example on how to use the GStreamer GstBaseTransform in C?

Tags: c, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

[GstBaseTransform](https://developer.gnome.org/gstreamer-libs/stable/GstBaseTransform.html) is the class intended for the simple image processing and analysis in GStreamer. Being new to GStreamer, I am looking for some more or less complete plugin that I could use for understanding how to implement mine. Unfortunately, the [Plugin Writers Guide](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/basics/index.html?gi-language=c) does not cover it, and in general I cannot find a complete source code of any simple enough example that uses it. Most of the websites I Google out simply repeat the documentation, some specialized code for [Freescale in GitHub](https://github.com/Freescale/gstreamer-imx/blob/master/src/blitter/video_transform.c) and also [GLES](https://github.com/geomatsi/gst-simple/blob/master/gles2.c) project are the closest thing I was so far able to find. It is, however, a specialized production code with lots of stuff to remove before trying to understand the rest.

Is it possible to get a complete example/source code of the plugin that uses GstBaseTransform for something very simple, like drawing line over the image?

GStreamer pipeline can be easily launched from the command line like "`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! the_plugin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`".

Comment: This looks a lot like a resource request. Perhaps *you* should provide a framework that for example sets up the stream otherwise, and then leaves the plugin part for answerers.

Comment: I provided the two samples that I would have been happy to know when I started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend a combination of documentation and the element builder. The element builder gives you a template for plugins based on several bases classes including basetransform. The tool can be found at `tools/gst-element-maker` in the `gst-plugins-bad` repository.

Then the documentation of the baseclass - e.g. https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/base/gstbasetransform.html?gi-language=c

Usually the documentation explains in general how the class is expected to work and does have some documentation on the most important/significant functions.

For basetransform your most important function is going to be `transform` or `transform_ip` depending whether your plugin will work in `in-place` mode or not. There you can do your processing - like writing a line into an image buffer.

Comment: The link doesn't work. You might try https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/base/gstbasetransform.html?gi-language=c instead

Comment: https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php?title=Creating_a_New_GStreamer_Element_or_Application_Using_Templates also worths reading